# Using specific fields from Model A on Model B. Circular import error

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I was trying to use coverage_amount, policy_length on models/User.py from models/Policy.py and when I import it using **"from .policy import Policy"** I'm encountering circular import because there is already an import in Policy.py which is **"from .user import User"**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import logging
import os
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, UserManager
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Q
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import (
    GenericForeignKey, GenericRelation)
**#from .policy import Policy**

from .extras import TimeStampedModel

logger = logging.getLogger('digiinsurance.models')

__all__ = ['User', 
           'Insuree']


**class Insuree(TimeStampedModel):**
 user = models.OneToOneField(
    'User', related_name='insuree', null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    primary_key=True)
 #coverage_amount = models.ForeignKey(Policy, on_delete=models.CASCADE, max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
 #policy_length = models.ForeignKey(Policy, on_delete=models.CASCADE, max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)



import logging
import os
import re
from datetime import datetime
from decimal import Decimal

from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import (
GenericForeignKey, GenericRelation)
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Q
from django.shortcuts import reverse

from .extras import TimeStampedModel, ArchivedModel
from .managers import PolicyManager
**from .user import User
from kyc.models import TemplateID**
from .company import Company

logger = logging.getLogger('samplename.models')

__all__ = ['Policy']

**class Policy(TimeStampedModel):**

 policy_length = models.FloatField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
 coverage_amount = models.FloatField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
```

Now, how can I use the coverage_amount, policy length from policy.py on user.py. I was trying to make a POST endpoint

Comment: Can you post your actual code, including the import statements, instead of trying to explain them?

Comment: In the foreign key can you try wrapping the model name in single or double quotes. Eg. `some_field = models.ForeignKey('app_name.model_name', ...other options...)` If i have models in a different app, i do it like this instead of importing it.